# How can I increase the number of subdivisions for functions in `scipy.integrate.dblquad`?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, integral

I'm using `scipy.integrate.dblquad`, and I get this error:

```
UserWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
If increasing the limit yields no improvement ...
```

I want to increase this limit to see if the integral is well-converged. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) specifies how to do this for `scipy.integrate.quad` (that function takes the maximum number of iterations as an argument), but not for [`scipy.integrate.dblquad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html).  How can I increase the number of subdivisions for `dblquad`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simpler way of doing this is to use the `nquad` function instead of `dblquad`. Example code:

```
from scipy.integrate import nquad

options={'limit':100}
integral=nquad(func,[[xmin,xmax],[ymin,ymax]],
          args=(other_arg,),opts=[options,options])
```

Note that several of the arguments are lists. The elements of these lists apply to each of the coordinates in order. See the documentation for nquad [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html).

Answer (score 7):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py), `dblquad` *calls* `quad`, reading, simply:

```
return quad(_infunc,a,b,(func,gfun,hfun,args),epsabs=epsabs,epsrel=epsrel)
```

Therefore, you could implement this directly yourself with the additional `maxp1` argument.

```
from scipy import integrate

def _infunc(x,func,gfun,hfun,more_args):
    a = gfun(x)
    b = hfun(x)
    myargs = (x,) + more_args
    return quad(func,a,b,args=myargs)[0]

def custom_dblquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, args=(), epsabs=1.49e-8, 
                   epsrel=1.49e-8, maxp1=50, limit=50):
    return integrate.quad(_infunc, a, b, (func, gfun, hfun, args), 
                          epsabs=epsabs, epsrel=epsrel, maxp1=maxp1, limit=limit)
```

Comment: Do you know of any ways to do this that don't involve modifying the source code?

Comment: I don't mean modify the source code, I mean call `quad` with those arguments, plus `maxpl`, yourself.

Comment: I've added an example implementation

Comment: @jonrsharpe, would you be able please to write an implementation of the above for the current ```dblquad``` ? Thank you https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.0/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L530-L602